Counting the number of points in buffered region
I have a point data (Lon Lat) imported through csv file in GEE. I want to count the number of points within a buffered region (In this case, i want to count the number of points within 100m around building)
var jpn = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/sat-io/open-datasets/VIDA_COMBINED/JPN")

//clip
var ms_clip = jpn.filterBounds(roi)

//count building number
print((ms_clip).size());


//Add building to map
Map.addLayer(ms_clip,{color:'blue'},'Microsoft Buldings of Tokyo');

//Set center
Map.centerObject(roi,13);
Map.setOptions("Satellite");



// Buffer each building by 100 meters
var bufferedBuildings = ms_clip.map(function(feature) {
  return feature.buffer(100); // Buffer by 100 meters
});

// Add buffered buildings to the map
Map.addLayer(bufferedBuildings, {color: 'red'}, 'Buffered Buildings (100m)');



// Count the number of R2 points within each buffer
var pointsInBuffer = bufferedBuildings.map(function(building) {
  var pointsInside = r2.filterBounds(building.geometry()); // Points within this buffer
  return building.set('point_count', pointsInside.size()); // Add count as a property
});

// Calculate the total number of points within all buffers
var totalPointsInBuffers = pointsInBuffer.aggregate_sum('point_count');
print('Total R2 points within buffers:', totalPointsInBuffers);

// Add layers to map for visualization
Map.addLayer(r2, {color: 'blue'}, 'R2 Points');

There are 198 points in the r2 data.  However, the result(R2 points within buffers) I get is 3182 which is more than the number of points. What is causing this and how can i fix this?

You are iterating the buffered buildings and counting how many points fall inside the buffer. However, a point can fall inside multiple buffered buildings, leading to an incorrectly inflated point count.
There is a second, trickier problem. For some reason, it seems like some buildings end up with unbounded geometries after buffering. They will always intersect all points, further blowing up your count.
Without digging into the reason of the buffering problem, you can perhaps simply filter these buildings out. A simple solution to the first issue is to iterate over the points and checking if they intersect any buffered building.
var bufferedBuildings = ms_clip.map(function(feature) {
  var buffered = feature
    .buffer(100)
  return ee.Algorithms.If(
    buffered.geometry().isUnbounded(), 
    null,
    buffered
  )
}, true)

print('bufferedBuildings size', bufferedBuildings.size())
Map.addLayer(bufferedBuildings, {color: 'red'}, 'Buffered Buildings (100m)')

var pointsInBuffer = r2
  .map(function (point) {
    var building = bufferedBuildings
      .filterBounds(point.geometry())
      .first()
    return point.set('building', building)
  })
  .filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['building']))
  
var totalPointsInBuffers = pointsInBuffer.size()

https://code.earthengine.google.com/47ef986db28f0aa38aab72e660dd8fe1

Thx for the answer. When i try the code you provided, i get an error 「Number (Error)
The service is currently unavailable.」　probably because there is too many points? Can  this be solved by exporting the result to google Drive?

It sounds like a temporary EE problem. You had only some 200 points, that shouldn't be a problem.
